# How to install Need for Speed Shift 1-2 game?

Tags: wine, games

Is there any way to install either Shift 1 or Shift 2 on Ubuntu?

Comment: additionally you should also give speed dreams a try.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably be able to run the application using [Wine](http://winehq.org) [image: Install wine]. Wine is a compatibility layer for Windows executables, allowing a number of Windows applications to run on Linux / Ubuntu.

According to the [Wine AppDB entry for NFS Shift 1](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10387), the application does have fairly good support and (assuming the patch is installed) should play with little or no problems.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if those two are supported by [PlayOnLinux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/PlayOnLinux) [image: Install PlayOnLinux] as yet, but that should be your best bet. Installation is automated.

Edit: as George said, Wine (what powers PlayOnLinux) should be able to run it. You will just need to know what you are doing if you encounter problems installing ;).

Answer (score 3):

Speed Dreams is a nice linux option for racing. The easiest install method that works for me is located here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/speed-dreams-140-ubuntu-deb.html